# что за скобки (первые) в java-коде Function var = (Function)foo.getSymbolFunction();?

Tags: java, синтаксис

Что означают первые скобки в строке кода java:

```
Function svaya_fn = (Function)inet_svaya.getSymbolFunction();
```

?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведение типов. В данном случае объект, возвращаемый функцией `getSymbolFunction`, будет приведен к типу `Function`. Если приведение невозможно, то будет выкинуто исключение `ClassCastException`